# struct as unknown argument 

Tags: c, struct, arguments

I know how to pass an unknown amount of arguments from unknown types to a function. 
I mean something like this:

```
char* plugins_entry(const char* data, ...);
```

Now I am trying to pass a struct besides a few other arguments to that function. I have the same struct declared (or defined?) in both files (main.c and plugins.c). But when I try to "filter" the irc struct passed from the main.c out and parse the data in the irc struct from the plugins.c, I don't get anything usefull. When I call the function I get a segementation fault.

This is the important part from the main.c:

```
struct irc_data {
char nick[32];
char user[32];
char host[64];
char chan[32];
char message[512];
int is_ready;
};

....

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    ....
    struct irc_data *irc = malloc(sizeof(struct irc_data));
    ....
    (*lib_plugin)("r",irc);  // call the function in plugins.c 
    ....
}
```

And here the hole plugins.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <string.h>

struct irc_data{
    char nick[32];
    char user[32];
    char host[64];
    char chan[32];
    char message[512];
    int is_ready;
};

char* plugins_entry(const char* data, ...) {
    int i;
    struct irc_data *irc = malloc(sizeof(struct irc_data));

    va_list args;
    va_start(args, data);

    for(i=0; data[i] != '\0'; ++i){
        if(data[i] == 'r'){
            irc = data[i];
        }
    }

    va_end(args);

    printf("\n\n------------------------\n");
    printf("What we got here: %s\n",irc->nick);
    printf("\n------------------------\n\n");


    return "done";
}
```

So, I am pretty sure that I am doing something wrong with the pointers.

Could you please help me out here?

Thank you

~ Tectu

Comment: Fyi, you shouldn't use fixed-size buffers for anything but `message` (where 512 is required as per the RFC). Everything else depends on the ircd used. While nicks are unlikely to be longer than 30 chars and usernames/idents are unlikely to be longer than 10 chars, a channel name may very well be longer than 32 chars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line `irc = data[i]` doesn't make any sense. You need to call `va_arg`:

```
if(data[i] == 'r') {
    irc = va_arg(args, struct irc *);
}
```

Also, the `malloc` in `plugins_entry` is useless, it will only leak memory.

Comment: Thank you very much, that works! And yes, it's makeing much more sense to me :D

Answer (score 2):

You don't extract the pointer to the struct using `va_args()`. With that, you should be able to directly use your struct:

```
struct irc_data *irc = va_args(args, struct irc *);
```

Note that you don't need to use malloc in this function as long as you don't want to copy explicitly. As your struct is already located on the heap (it's malloc'ed in main.c), you can just use it directly by using the pointer.